# QuickSight sync colors across multiple visuals

Tags: data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to sync the colors for visuals and am running into some challenges. I have for example a vertical stack bar chart with group by source (so the bar displays multiple client revenue with the aggregate being total revenue). I have a second visual, a donut chart, which has products purchased by client. I want Client A color in the bar chart to be the same as Client A in the donut chart. Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any code your are currently working on? any error log? Please also check [example]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Themes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/themes-in-quicksight.html) -> Data -> Data colors. However, colors are assigned in order, so make sure your charts are sorted by the same field.

Comment: So it sounds like the way to align on colors is really to make sure the order for each is the same as opposed to some direct way of assigning color by source?

Comment: Correct, if charts contain significant number of groups/sources, it may be a tedious task to assign a color to each group individually on all charts.

Comment: Thanks @sashko appreciate it.